# Wont restart httpd

Tags: apache, centos7, httpd.conf

Please assist, when trying to restart apache I get a failed message. Why is the webserver crashing?

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-03-28 22:55:07 SAST; 15s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 11038 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11036 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11036 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 httpd[11036]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the nex...onf:1
Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 httpd[11036]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully quali...ssage
Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 kill[11038]: kill: cannot find process ""
Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 28 22:55:07 nov004-truserv-jhb1-001 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Looks more like a package installation issue than a configuration problem. Tripple check dependencies, if possible try a slightly different version.

Comment: Oh, and we can assume you installed the http server from a clean and standard package repository meant for CentOS?

Comment: check the apache server error.log first